# How to run sh script from jenkins

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, hudson

I need launch sh script from jenkins, it is simple, but my script change symlink for JAVA_HOME, in fact im switching between JDK versions using sh script. It works when Im launching job without jenkins(job writen on bash), but it does not working under jenkins... Jenkins remember JAVA_HOME after start and use this path... how can I change JAVA_HOME from sh script under jenkins ? may be from script invoke jenkins reload config if it's possible... thx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just try as below ;

```
    public static void execShellCmd(String cmd) {  
        try {  
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();  
            Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", cmd });  
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();  
            System.out.println("exit value: " + exitValue);  
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
            String line = "";  
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {  
                System.out.println("exec response: " + line);  
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e);  
        }  
    }
```

For more details : [Shell Script Running with java](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/30145-running-shell-script-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!! soulution is simple, I have sh script that was launched in jenkins job like this:
    ./MY_SCRIPT.sh

And after that script launched under jenkins and I had problems with switching JAVA_HOME.

All is need to do launch script like this:
    sh MY_SCRIPT.sh
and it will launched smt like from the system.